# In cucumber.js, disable a scenario and report it as Pending even if steps are implemented

Tags: gherkin, cucumberjs

I want to disable certain scenarios in my Cucumber.js feature files because even though steps are implemented (reused from other scenarios), the code will fail under these circumstances because the feature is not yet implemented.

However, I don't want to use the `@ignore` tag on these scenarios as they then aren't seen in the output report and the team forget about them.

What's the best way to do this without explicitly adding a dummy "Given this is not yet implemented" step to each of the new scenarios?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one idea I had, but it's not built-in to the framework itself. I'm just exploiting the feature of a `Before` step which only runs for certain tags

```
Before({ tags: "@TODO" }, function() {

    return "pending";

});
```

Not sure if there's a more framework-centric way to do it?

Comment: Yep that's how the docs say to do it https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md

Comment: @Raymond Kelly if you add that as an answer I'll mark it as the selected

Answer (score 1):

Your above answer is the best way I can see to do it and is actually the way that the cucumber-js team recommend doing so as seen in https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/hooks.md#skipping-in-a-before-hook

They give two available statuses to use from as seen in https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md#pending-steps